# Take data from a txt file, Parse it, and put into CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, parsing

I've been searching the web for a solution to my exact problem but all the answers are outdated. I have a text file that contains data in this form:

> FIRST NAME: xxx 
>   MIDDLE NAME: xxx 
>   LAST NAME: xxx 
>   BIRTHDAY: xxx 
>   HEIGHT: xxx 
>   WEIGHT: xxx 
>   ADDRESS: xxx 
>   CITY, STATE ZIP: xxx

There is more than one of these entries in the file. I need to take the data from "xxx", basically everything after each ":" and put it into one line with each "xxx" being separated by commas. This is so that I can use it as a CSV file. I want to put this information into an Excel sheet.

So I would want it to look like this:

```
firstname,middlename,lastname,birthday,height,weight,address,citystatezip
```

This is what I have, I do not know where to go from here.

```
with open('info.txt') as file:
   for rec in file:
      print rec.split(':')[1]
```

This code is just suppose to print each thing after ":". I can't really get it to work and also have no idea how I am going to put it in the format I desire.

Comment: How are the solutions you tried outdated? which ones did you try? what is your current code?

Comment: This is the only sort of help I have found on the subject, I tried using this and came up with nothing. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnY-jz2D4Qs&t=325s)

Comment: Reading raw text files is the same now as it was in much much older versions of python. So forget anything being outdated.

Comment: Do you know how to open a text file and read it line by line? Does each entry in the file always contain the same fields, in the same order?

Comment: We're happy to help you with this project, but you need to show some effort. Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service, so please add some relevant code that you've written, and clearly explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I have given more information. I apologize, this is my first time using Stack overflow. I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out myself and this is what I have resorted to.

Comment: Ok, that's a little better. But it _does_ sound like you need to work through a beginner's Python tutorial. Rather than just printing the data from each line as you read it, you need to save it somehow. I suggest saving it into a list. And each time you hit a line that starts with `"FIRST NAME"` (or hit the end of the file), you can print the data from the previous person.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
$ cat file.csv
FIRST NAME: xxx 
MIDDLE NAME: xxx 
LAST NAME: xxx 
BIRTHDAY: xxx 
HEIGHT: xxx 
WEIGHT: xxx 
ADDRESS: xxx 
CITY, STATE ZIP: xxx
```

You can do:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    data=[[e.strip() for e in line.split(':')] for line in f]

print zip(*data)
```

Prints:

```
[('FIRST NAME', 'MIDDLE NAME', 'LAST NAME', 'BIRTHDAY', 'HEIGHT', 'WEIGHT', 'ADDRESS', 'CITY, STATE ZIP'), ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')]
```

`zip` transposes the matrix so the header is on top.

So then you can do:

```
>>> zip(*data)[0]
('FIRST NAME', 'MIDDLE NAME', 'LAST NAME', 'BIRTHDAY', 'HEIGHT', 'WEIGHT', 'ADDRESS', 'CITY, STATE ZIP')
```

Then to get what you state that you want:

```
>>> ','.join([e.replace(' ','').replace(',','').lower() for e in zip(*data)[0]]) 
firstname,middlename,lastname,birthday,height,weight,address,citystatezip
```

If you want to first column (the items after the colon) you can do the same method:

```
>>> ','.join([e.replace(' ','').replace(',','').lower() for e in zip(*data)[1]])
xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx
```

Or more simply:

```
>>> ','.join(zip(*data)[1])
```

Comment: OP stated: *So I would want it to look like this:* `firstname,middlename,lastname,birthday,height,weight,address,citystatezip` I showed how to do that.

Comment: Im getting invalid syntax for "zip"

Comment: You are typing something differently than I did. Step through the examples above. You will figure this out...